# Can require.resolve('module_name') find local modules?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm writing a yeoman-generator with sub-generators that I'm trying to reference like so:

Within the main generator:

```
require.resolve("generator-sub-generator")
```

which is throwing the following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'generator-sub-generator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.require.resolve (module.js:384:19)
    at module.exports.WebappGenBase.extend.composeJS (/Users/Liam/work/generator-main-generator/app/index.js:277:20)
    at /Users/Liam/work/generator-main-generator/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:395:14
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

I've already installed the sub generator locally and they appear to be working together fine, except for `require.resolve()`.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you saying doing `require("generator-sub-generator")` works but `require.resolve("generator-sub-generator")` finds nothing? Not super clear on the structure you are describing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! No, neither `require("generator-sub-generator")` nor `require.resolve("generator-sub-generator")` work, but `this.composeWith("sub-generator", options, settings)` does work.

Comment: I'm sure you have found a workaround by now, but I believe the issue is you need to do a require("./generator-sub-generator") to do a require of a local file

Answer (score 0):

It has been one year, but probably there is no index.js file in your folder